# How to pass the list value at redirect to action in mvc 2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I created on list at `createMaster` controller (`createMaster/CreateData`) and I want to pass that list to `DataEntry` Controller (`DataEntry/EntryData`).

When user clicks the submit button in `CreateData` view I need to redirect and pass the list to `EntryData` view. How do I pass the list value at redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TempData["model"] = model;
return RedirectToAction("Success");
```

and inside the

```
var model = TempData["model"]
```

Comment: Thank u friend. but TempData is not proper approach in my company because some one can directly enter to that EntryData view that will shown the list via tempdata